# Copy new paragraphs in an HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, styles

I have an HTML form that looks like this:

`<textarea class="input" name="content" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="hard"></textarea>`
The value in the textarea is then transfered into a database so it can be displayed later. What I ask myself is: how can the style and the form of the text be remained, so that when a user enters a text, all his new paragraphs are also being saved in the database?

The question could also be: how does the form, which I am currently using on stackoverflow.com, work, how does it save the paragraphs that I make and how do the options on top work, which can make my text bold, italic etc.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to research about markdown answers here is one https://stackoverflow.com/a/35057668/175554

and another one [How can I convert HTML to markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049936/how-can-i-convert-html-to-markdown)